# Получение всех наследников класса

Tags: c#, namespace, классы

Задача такая: мне надо получить все классы для создания хэша из пространства имен System.Security.Cryptography. Они все наследники класса HashAlgoritm. Я где-то видел подобное делалось для поиска всех классов-насследников интерфейса через Assembly. Как такое провенуть? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
Type ourtype = typeof(HashAlgorithm); // Базовый тип
IEnumerable<Type> list = Assembly.GetAssembly(ourtype).GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(ourtype));  // using System.Linq

foreach(Type itm in list){
    Console.WriteLine(itm);
}
```

Получите всех наследников (из той-же сборки что и базовый тип)

Comment: То что надо! Спасибо большое!

Comment: А если надо не только из той же сборки? =)